# Adding Parameters in Routing URL Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I have some problem with routing and parameters.

I have routing in routes.php like this :

```
$route['register/(:any)'] = 'member/register/$1';
```

And in my controller I have like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Page_model');
        $this->load->model('member_model');
        $this->load->model('login_model');

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('form');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $type = $this->uri->segment(2);

        var_dump($type);
        exit();

        if ($slug != NULL) 
        {
            $data['page'] = $this->Page_model->get_page($slug);

            if (empty($data['page'])) 
            {
                // show_404();
                $data['page'] = new stdClass();
                $data['page']->page_template = 'forofor';
                $data['page']->title = 'Page Not Found';
                $data['page']->meta_description = 'Page Not Found';
                $data['page']->meta_keywords = 'Page Not Found';
            }
            else
            {
                $data['slider'] = $this->Page_model->get_slider($data['page']->page_id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $data['page'] = $this->Page_model->get_page('home');
            $data['slider'] = $this->Page_model->get_slider($data['page']->page_id);
        }

        $data['head_title'] = $data['page']->title;

        // load all settings and data
        $data['settings'] = $this->Page_model->get_settings();
        $data['gallery'] = $this->Page_model->get_gallery();

        $data['meta'] = 
            array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'description', 
                    'content' => $data['page']->meta_description
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'keywords',
                    'content' => $data['page']->meta_keywords
                )
            );

        // $data['meta'] = $this->meta;

        $data['menu'] = $this->Page_model->get_menu('frontend','header');
        $data['settings'] = $this->Page_model->get_settings();
        $data['notice'] = $this->session->flashdata('notice');

        // $this->load->view('frontend/template/index_full', $data);

        $this->load->view('frontend/template/head', $data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/pre_header');
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/header');
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/modal');
        //$this->load->view('frontend/template/modal_registration');
        /*if ($page[0]->page_template != 'forofor' && $data['page']->slider != 0) 
        {
            $this->load->view('frontend/template/slider');
        }*/
        if ($slug != 'home' && $slug != NULL) 
        {
            //$this->load->view('member/'.$data['page']->page_template);
            $this->load->view('member/register');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('frontend/template/slider');
            $this->load->view('frontend/page_template/homepage');
        }
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/pre_footer');
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/footer');
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/js');
        $this->load->view('frontend/template/closing_body_html');
    }
}
```

But if I input the routes in my browser it gives me 404 Page not found

This is my routes :

```
127.0.0.1/project/register/buyer
```

And `127.0.0.1/project/` is my Base URL

Anyone knows why it could be happen ?

Thank you.

Comment: You have posted your `Register` controller and calling `Member` controllers `Register` function in your routes which is wrong,so please let us know what exactly you require

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your routing is wrong. According to your post you are setting `Member` controller then register method.

Try below code

```
$route['register/(:any)'] = 'register/index/$1';
$route['register/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'register/index/$1/$2'; // Optional
```

The second option is only optional:

Answer (score 3):

This is how routes work in Codeigniter

> Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and
>   its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a URI
>   normally follow this pattern:
>
> example.com/class/function/id/ In some instances, however, you may
>   want to remap this relationship so that a different class/method can
>   be called instead of the one corresponding to the URL.
>
> For example, let’s say you want your URLs to have this prototype:
>
> example.com/product/1/ example.com/product/2/ example.com/product/3/
>   example.com/product/4/ Normally the second segment of the URL is
>   reserved for the method name, but in the example above it instead has
>   a product ID. To overcome this, CodeIgniter allows you to remap the
>   URI handler.

Reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

So,the routes follow this syntax

```
$route['route_url'] = 'controller/method/$paramater';
```

So,your route will be

Let me know your queries

```
$route['register/(:any)'] = 'register/index/$1';
```